# R. Добавить правильную легенду на график ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Мне нужно построить график, который бы раскрашивал мои данные в соответствующие цвета. Данные пронумерованы по порядку и через каждые 64 образца цвет этих образцов должен меняться.
Нужный график я получила:
[image: График с раскрашенными образцами]

Теперь мне нужно составить легенду к этому графику, где в заголовке "а = " и написано, что красному цвету (для 1..64 образцов) соответствует а=0.25, зеленому (для 65..128) соответствует а=0.5, желтому - а=0.75, синему - а = 1.

Код к уже созданному графику:

```
col <- with(mds.data, ifelse(mds.data.Sample<65, "red3", 
                         ifelse(mds.data.Sample>=65 & mds.data.Sample<129, "forestgreen",
                                ifelse(mds.data.Sample>=129 & mds.data.Sample<193, "darkblue","orange"))))


ggplot(data=mds.data, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Sample)) +
  geom_text(show.legend = TRUE,col=col) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(paste("PCoA1 - ", mds.var.per[1], "%", sep="")) +
  ylab(paste("PCoA2 - ", mds.var.per[2], "%", sep="")) +
  ggtitle("PCoA plot using dtw-distance")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="a =",labels=c("0.25", "0.5","0.75","1"))
```

Легенда почему-то не создается. Перепробовала еще разные способы помимо `scale_color_discrete`, но нужная легенда так и не создается:(

Выслушаю любые предложения, как можно создать правильную легенду к моему графику.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать общий датафрейм для всех данных, в т.ч. добавить туда col. Тогда заработает с минимальными правками

```
ggplot(data=mds.data, aes(x=X, y=Y, col=col)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Sample), fill = legend) +
  и т.д.
```

Comment: Легенда появилась, но в этом случае цвета оказались не те, которые были указаны, и при этом они не соответствуют нужным значениям параметра а. То есть, к примеру, значения образцов 1..64 согласно расставленным цветам соответствуют а=1, а должны соответствовать а=0.25.

Comment: Не понятно. 
Приведите воспроизводимый код с данными - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.